# ArrayList nullPointerException

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I am getting a `NullPointerException` while adding objects to `hello` `ArrayList`. I want to add objects at specific indices, so if I don't add `null` objects to the array before hand, I get `IndexOutOfBoundsException` when I try to add at an index whose previous index hasn't been populated yet. Why am I getting a `NullPointerException` and is there any other way to achieve it?

```
    public void test()
    {
        ArrayList<TEST> temp = new ArrayList<>(4);

        temp.add(0,new TEST(2));
        temp.add(1,new TEST(3));
        temp.add(2,new TEST(1));
        temp.add(3,new TEST(0));


        for(int i=0; i<4; i++)
            Log.e("test", "i: "+i+ " index: "+temp.get(i).x);


        ArrayList<TEST> hello = new ArrayList<>(4);
        hello.add(null);
        hello.add(null);
        hello.add(null);
        hello.add(null);

        hello.add(temp.get(0).x, temp.get(0));
        hello.add(temp.get(1).x, temp.get(1));
        hello.add(temp.get(2).x, temp.get(2));
        hello.add(temp.get(3).x, temp.get(3));


        Log.e("test", "___________________________");
        for(int i=0; i<4; i++)
            Log.e("test", "i: "+i+ " index: "+hello.get(i).x);

    }

    public class TEST
    {
        int x;

        public TEST(int x) {
            this.x = x;
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you write

```
hello.add(temp.get(0).x, temp.get(0));
```

you don't replace the `null` you put in the `temp.get(0).x` index. You just move that `null` to the next index.

Therefore, in the loop :

```
    for(int i=0; i<4; i++)
        Log.e("test", "i: "+i+ " index: "+hello.get(i).x);
```

you encounter a null value, so `hello.get(i).x` throws `NullPointerException`.

change it to

```
    hello.set(temp.get(0).x, temp.get(0));
    hello.set(temp.get(1).x, temp.get(1));
    hello.set(temp.get(2).x, temp.get(2));
    hello.set(temp.get(3).x, temp.get(3));
```

in order to replace all the null values with non null values.

Comment: And it would also be helpful to make the output more robust, like this: `Log.e("test", "i: "+i+ " index: "+(hello.get(i)==null ? "" : hello.get(i).x));`

Answer (score 0):

You can override `ArrayList.set()` method to add objects at specific indexes:

```
public class SparseArrayList<E> extends ArrayList<E> {

    @Override
    public E set(int index, E element) {
        while (size() <= index) add(null);
        return super.set(index, element);
    }

}
```

Answer (score -4):

I think you get the error because you try to add more then 4 elements to the list that initials to 4 maximum capacity.

Comment: The initial capacity is just that, an initial capacity. It is *not* a maximum capacity.